# Problems with react. js hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, framer-motion

I am programming a protfolio website and I am using react-router dom and framer motion. I want my website to be smooth while passing from one page to other. Here is the error

```
bundle.js:1075 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
printWarning @ bundle.js:1075
error @ bundle.js:1052
```

I had two package jason but I do not know if that can affect this, I have installed twice react router dom apparently and then deleted the second package jason and nothing. I have not installed twice react. Here is App.js:

```
import { BrowserRouter, NavLink, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import LocationProvider from "./components/locationProvider";
import RoutesWithAnimation from "./components/routesWithAnimation";
import { AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Header />
      <LocationProvider>
        <AnimatePresence>
          <RoutesWithAnimation />
        </AnimatePresence>
      </LocationProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is LocationProvider.js

```
import { AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";
import React from "react";

function LocationProvider({ children }) {
  return <AnimatePresence>{children}</AnimatePresence>;
}

export default LocationProvider;
```

Here is RoutesWithAnimationjs

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { Home } from "./Home";
import { About } from "./About";
import { Contact } from "./Contact";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";

function RoutesWithAnimation() {
  const location = useLocation();
  return (
    <AnimatePresence>
      <Routes location={location} key={location.key}>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
      </Routes>
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
}
export default RoutesWithAnimation;
```

Here is Home.js

```
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import React from "react";

const routeVariants = {
  initial: {
    y: "100vh",
  },
  final: {
    y: "0vh",
  },
};

export function Home() {
  return (
    <motion.div
      variants={routeVariants}
      initial="initial"
      animate="final"
      exit="initial"
      className="home component"
    >
      <h1> Home Component </h1>
    </motion.div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you share your version of react and react-dom from package.json please?

Comment: "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",

Comment: Seems to work fine for me https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-oskar-2vzh5e?file=/package.json